# How do I add javascript code to number field?

Tags: javascript, webforms, forms

I have a Number type field in webform for phone number, in chrome it does not allow to enter characters while in mozilla it allows and on submit it shows "enter number" message. now i need to add this script to the webform field so that in mozilla also it wont allow adding characters.

Only numbers please:

```
<input type="number" name="someid" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /> 



  <script>
    function isNumberKey(evt){
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
return true;
 }    
</script>
```

how can I use this script in `hook_form_alter()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom module then you add following code :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custommodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'webformCustomID')) {

    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'custommodule') . '/custom.js';
  }
}
```

OR

You can do by using module

[Webform Javascript Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_javascript_field)

> With Webform Javascript Field you can use custom JavaScript or Jquery
>   snippets for all your Webform form elements.

Comment: yes i want to create a custom module only . but how can i add onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" this to the code?

Comment: when you create custom module add js file in module  and you js code write in js file like custom.js

Comment: i mean to ask how will i add this attribute onkeypress in wwebformform?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131716/using-jquery-to-set-onkeypress-attribute

Comment: In custom.js i have added :                                                                    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#edit-submitted-phone').keypress(isNumberKey(event));
});

function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}                but its not working .. what can be the issue.